# integrate facebook with google app engine

Tags: facebook, google-app-engine, python-2.7

I want to create an app in Python using google app engine that checks whether a user is logged in facebook or not. Like, if a user is logged in facebook then the Python app will display "Hello, fbusername", otherwise it will display "Hello, Guest!"

Answer (score 2):

I guess this sample is exactly what you want?
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/samples/canvas/